# How to tell an AppImage file from a regular executable?

Tags: file-format

The question is pretty much in the title. If I launch the `file` command on an AppImage I get:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

while on a regular executable I get:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b6e2c0d6aaa2a3cb1555e8e7511e67424eb9ebeb, stripped
```

Is it possible to identify the first file as an AppImage by looking at the output of the `file` command? Is there any other command I should use for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `magic number` of the file with `xxd` tool.
For AppImage the number is `0x414902`.

```
xxd ucdmap.appimage-0.2.0-x86_64.AppImage| head -1
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 4149 0200 0000 0000  .ELF....AI......
```

[AppImage Magic Number](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/issues/6#issuecomment-345829772)